# Why does JavaScript returns that?

Tags: javascript

So, my question is why:

`1.7976931348623157E+308 > 10^16` returns `17` in Google Chrome,
and `(1.7976931348623157E+308) > (10^16)` returns `true`?

Because it looks like these operations are the same.

Comment: `10^16` are you trying to do exponentiation? The operator for that is `**`, not `^`. `^` is bitwise XOR.

Comment: `^` is the bitwise XOR operator. `7^9=14`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first expression is equivalent to

```
(1.7976931348623157E+308 > 10) ^ 16
```

or

```
true ^ 16
```

Which seems strange, until you realize that

```
true == 1
```

is true.

Comment: To add to this, the reason why the first expression is parsed like that is due to [Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) - bitwise XOR `^` has a lower precedence than the comparison operators `>`, so the XOR is performed after the comparison.

Comment: Helped. Thank you.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that `^` is an XOR operator and not an exponent operator